# Raspberry + Fedora, wrong CPU load average

Tags: pi-3, cpu, fedora

For some reason, my "top" command is showing wrong **cpu load average**. Like 100% cpu usage everytime, but, in fact, the cpu is 100% idle.

It's a Raspberry 3, running Fedora 28. CPU temperature is below 46C, so, the CPU is really idle. No hardware changed in last months.

Any idea why?

```
top - 21:47:52 up  1:02,  1 user,  load average: 4.00, 4.00, 4.00
Tasks: 139 total,   1 running,  84 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.5 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.0 id,  0.0 wa,  4.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :   996680 total,   210940 free,   294880 used,   490860 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   249852 total,   249852 free,        0 used.   680308 avail Mem
```

The CPU is idle, but the load average is wrong:

`load average: 4.00, 4.00, 4.00`

Using `iotstat`:

```
[root@raspberry ~]# iostat
Linux 5.0.5-100.fc28.armv7hl (raspberry)        04/08/2019      _armv7l_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.16    0.11    1.21    0.12    0.00   98.40
```

Comment: You `top` shows about 99% idle. You can't  deduce idle from CPU temperature.

Comment: Yes, but see the counters: `load average: 4.00, 4.00, 4.00`

Comment: If your point is the load average, then you should edit the question and say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the vhciq driver in the 5.0.x kernel:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2881

Reverting back to a 4.x kernel appears to solve this problem.  I rolled back to the following with no issues:

https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1231413

Comment: Yes, my kernel is 5.0.5-100.fc28.armv7hl. Probably you're right.

Comment: You're right! My kernel was updated saturday, and I rebooted sunday, when the problem started:

    `Removed:
      kernel.armv7hl 4.20.15-100.fc28          kernel-core.armv7hl 4.20.15-100.fc28 
      kernel-modules.armv7hl 4.20.15-100.fc28 

    Installed:
      kernel.armv7hl 5.0.5-100.fc28                                                 
      kernel-core.armv7hl 5.0.5-100.fc28                                            
      kernel-modules.armv7hl 5.0.5-100.fc28`

Answer (score 1):

kernel-5.0.9-200.fc29.armv7hl appears to have resolved this issue.